# Best way to install a local package

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I am trying to install a package from `ppa:lubomir-brindza/nautilus-typeahead`. I do not have `sudo` access on machine, so I want to install the executables locally. What is the best way to do this? I understand that the package won't be automatically updated, I just want to be able to use the executables.

To reiterate, I do not have sudo access. So I do not think I can build from source, since that would require installing the build-dependencies.